# Можно ли у компонента CheckBox, текст с "галкой" поменять местами?

Tags: java, android

Использую компонент CheckBox вот так:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbObjOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Объект:  "
 />
```

Получается сначала расположена галка, а потом текст.

Можно ли поменять местами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbObjOn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Объект:  "
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:drawableEnd="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
/>
```

UPD. Если разрабатываете под API >= 17 можно проще:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```